# mongo: command not found on mongodb 6.0 docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

After installing the latest mongo docker images through

```
docker pull mongo:latest

docker run --name mongo -d mongo:latest
```

Then enter into this docker container and run `mongo`

```
docker exec -it mongo /bin/sh
# mongo
/bin/sh: 2: mongo: not found

# env
HOSTNAME=2ffb8dac9717
HOME=/data/db
TERM=xterm
MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
MONGO_MAJOR=6.0
JSYAML_VERSION=3.13.1
GOSU_VERSION=1.12
MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.org
PWD=/
MONGO_VERSION=6.0.1
```

After checking the `/usr/bin` folder, there is no `mongo` under it. Is there anything missing here? How to run mongo shell in mongodb 6.0 docker?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

> The [mongo shell is removed from MongoDB 6.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#legacy-mongo-shell-removed). The replacement is
> [mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/).

Comment: Does the trick! Thank you! I'm at the 100th tutorial trying to setup my podman/kubernetes/golang/mongo/postgres/microservices cluster. Another problem bytes the dust! Keep on grinding guys!

Comment: So now you do `docker exec -it mongo mongosh` to get into shell. It will also provide connect string on launch so you can use some GUI like MongoDb ComPass to connect to it.

Comment: ChatGPT had suggested using the mongo command in a docker-compose.yml file to check the official MongoDB 6 container health status and it did not work. You gave the proper explanation. Thanks